# ubuntu 18.04 my system does not find audio device

Tags: pulseaudio

I tried all sort ways, followed recommendations. None helped. I cannot assign and find my audio speaker which is connected to a usb soundcard. Please help, i do not know how to proceed.

Thank in advance

Output of lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0718 Genesys Logic, Inc. IDE/SATA Adapter
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1c4f:0048 SiGma Micro 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1d50:6089 OpenMoko, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

type of soundcard:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=03 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  8 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0d8c ProdID=0014 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=C-Media Electronics Inc.
S:  Product=USB Audio Device
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid


rpj@rpj-T11:~$ pacmd list-cards | grep output\:
```

No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
rpj@rpj-T11:~$

Comment: file:///home/rpj/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202019-03-30%2012-00-12.png

Comment: What model is your USB sound card? Also, open up a terminal and type `lsusb` + hit Enter and post the output of it in your question by editing it.

Comment: Thanks, please now post the output of `pacmd list-cards | grep output\:`

Comment: by now I have come to the point of understanding why i have trouble. I simply do not use HdmI as monitor, I use a D-Sub. Now, Pulseaudio defaults audio to HdmI and therefore i cannot use my usb-soundcard.

Badly to say, for a newbie Ubuntu gives lots troubles for such simple problems. However, I do like the system but cannot solve it by myself. I guess I have to start learning all this terminal gimmics and shell stuff.

I reinstalle already 3 times the entire system, but still cannot use it by means of audio output.